# Admin - Load existing admin template as a submenu page

Tags: admin, sub-menu

I'm trying to save my client a few clicks. I've created a custom role of "Customer" and I'd like to get them to that screen, without having to have them click "Users" and then select the "Customer" role.

So, I have a custom menu called "Orders". I'd like to add a submenu called "Customers" and "load" this page:

users.php?role=custom

I'm guessing I have to use the callback function on add_submenu_page and then load that template? What's the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an interal link quite easily, it's the same approach you use for adding custom items, you simply exclude a callback function and set the menu slug to the applicable URL, here's an example.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_user_type_link' );
function add_user_type_link() {
    add_submenu_page( 'users.php', 'Customers', 'Customers', 'edit_users', 'users.php?role=customers' );
}
```

Adjust the code as appropriate(required cap, naming, etc..).

Comment: **NOTE:** Alternatively you can use [`add_users_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_users_page) in place of `add_submenu_page`.

Comment: Thanks for this! I had tried this unsuccessfully prior - I probably missed something, though, I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: It worked! Beautiful! In my case, I wanted it under my custom menu, so I used "manage-reports" (the slug of my custom menu) instead of "users.php".